# Managing db migrations with redis

Tags: java, redis, database-migration

I'm working on a Java app that uses Redis as its backend. As the app's grown, we've gotten to a point where we need to work with migrations (something analogous to migrations?) in Redis. Of course Redis is schemaless, but in a project of any reasonable size you inevitably end up implementing your own abstractions within redis.

For example, say we have a key-value pair like

```
redis:6379> get myapp:user:123
"Alice"
```

but we may decide months from now that we want to change our abstraction to something like

```
redis:6379> get myapp:user:123:name
"Alice"
```

Or maybe we want to keep the old key format, but change the value to a redis hash, or maybe to a serialized json string, etc.

The problem is that changing the code to create and expect keys in the new format is easy, but updating preexisting data is more difficult. e.g. We can make it so new users are saved with something like

```
redis:6379> set myapp:user:124:name Bob
```

but then we'll have data in two different formats:

```
redis:6379> get myapp:user:124:name
"Bob"
redis:6379> get myapp:user:123:name
(nil)
redis:6379> get myapp:user:123
"Alice"
```

Are there any best practices for dealing with this? Are there any good tools for this, or are we approaching this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: Previously I've used Active Record Migrations in Rails and think that something analogous might be useful here, but I haven't seen anything close to this...